# Aggregation Inheritance in Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, aggregation, composition

I am having a problem trying to create An array of type Forest.
This Forest Contains Both Animals & Objects. (Aggregation)
Animals are either X or Y 
Objects are either A or B 
I created a class for forest
I created classes for Animals & Objects.
My problem starts here.

```
public class Forest
{

    private AnimalType animals;
    private ObjectType stagnantObject;

    Forest[,] forestArray;

    Random rand = new Random();

    public enum AnimalType
    {
        Lion = 1, Elephant = 2, Deer = 3
    }

    public enum ObjectType
    {
        Rock = 1, Plant = 2, Tree = 3
    }

    public Forest(AnimalType animal)
    {
        animal = animals;
    }

    public Forest()
    {

    }

    public void createArray(int w, int h)
    {
        forestArray = new Forest[w, h];
    }

    public int[] randomPosition()
    {
        int upperbound = forestArray.GetUpperBound(0);
        int lowerbound = forestArray.GetUpperBound(1);
        int xCord;
        int yCord;
        xCord = rand.Next(0,upperbound);
        yCord = rand.Next(0,lowerbound);
        int [] array = new int [2];
        array[0] = xCord;
        array[1] = yCord;
        return array;
    }

    public Object initialzeArray(int l, int d, int e, int r, int t, int p)
    {
        int numOfLion = l;
        while(numOfLion != 0 )
        {
            int[] random = randomPosition();
            int x = random[0];
            int y = random[1];
            forestArray[x, y] = new Lion(); // this is wrong! How do i implement it correctly?? ***
            numOfLion--;
        }
```

Please if someone can clarify what is wrong, i have tried many code but i always end up with a problem, i have an flaw in my understanding. so if anyone can link me to an article or something to read that could help me, i have read alot and i am not getting anywhere. Also what is this problem called?? I had difficulty trying to come up with a title to this problem
Help is appreciated thank you

*****Edit
this is the error.
Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
***** Edit 
Upon initializing the forest, you are required to randomly allocate to the empty spaces a number of elephants, lions, deer, rocks, trees, and plants. These numbers are specified by the user.

So i have a Forest array, that has an object type animal, and Stagnant Object. 
I have worries that i am not using proper terminology. so please feel free to fix my vocabulary. 
Another question, is my deceleration of AnimalType & ObjectType in the correct class?

I have 1 Forest Class, 2 Abstract Classes, and 6 Concrete Classes.

But how do you code aggregation ??

Comment: Where are your class definitions?

Comment: And why do you call rocks, trees & plants stagnant? Stangnant: (of a body of water or the atmosphere of a confined space) having no current or flow and often having an unpleasant smell as a consequence.

Comment: @Enigmativity hey man, basically the class definitions are very simple. Abstract Animal Class and Concrete subClasses, Also the definition if stagnant is non moving, The definition of stagnate is what you just said. Dont worry i checked it.

Comment: The other definition I saw was _inactive, sluggish, slow, slow-moving, lethargic, static, flat, depressed, quiet, dull, declining, moribund, dying, dead, dormant, stagnating_. I wouldn't call rocks, trees & plants stagnant.

Comment: Anyway, if the definitions are simple then please post them in your question. It makes it easier for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
Forest[,] forestArray;
```

you're declaring `forestArray` as an array of `Forest`, but here

```
forestArray[x, y] = new Lion();
```

you want to add a `Lion` instance. `Lion` seems not to be derived from `Forest` but from `Animal`. (`Forest` does not make much sense anyway since it's the class that is containing the array). Try to declare `forestArray` as

```
Animal[,] forestArray;
```

and change

```
forestArray = new Forest[w, h];
```

to

```
forestArray = new Animal[w, h];
```

Comment: Okay i get it, but you see the array also has The stagnant objects (rocks trees plants). Basically i would like to include a timer that moves the animals in the array and if i run into an non stagnant Object ill have to check conditions.

Answer (score -2):

It may be that `Object` is a reserved word.

> Try changing `Object` to `ForestObject`

Comment: *"It may be that Object is a reserved word."*? No. It may not be that at all. Try it.